# Simple table partitioning?

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to learn about partitioning - I have a large MySQL database with the following structure:

```
Name (VARCHAR), Id (Int), DoB (Int), Height (Int)
```

Around 70% of the rows in this table do not have a value for DoB (this value is NULL), I wish to separate these from the rest of the table to speed up my queries to the remaining 30% of the table.

Example queries:

```
SELECT name FROM mytable WHERE Id = ' ' LIMIT 1;
INSERT INTO mytable (Height) VALUES (180) WHERE Id = '1234';
```

This is a very large table, and therefore this query take a while to execute - therefore using a partition may make sense to speed this up.

Is there a simple partition I can create to separate these?

I'm aware there are different types of partitioning (hash, key, list, column) and I'm a bit uncertain about how best to do this for my table?

Comment: When you say they do not have a value, I'm assuming they are _`NULL`_. Could you just add to your query `WHERE DoB IS NOT NULL` or am I missing the meaning of your question?

Comment: If they are indexed, null values are not present in the index.  If you use a query that accesses that column explicitly, particularly if it's a query driver, you will avoid the 70% of the rows that are null.  Partitioning works best if there is not a huge disparity in partition sizes.  If you decide to partition anyway, you will have to use "where DOB is not null" and then a default where it is.  In any case, as DOB is updated, the amount of work required by the DB to move from the 70% partition to the 30% will be very large.

Comment: what you need is an index not a partition.